# How can a client connect to a specific room via socketio

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a server which emits events (something like live updates) to multiple rooms within the `default` namespace of a `socket.io` server. The server does NOT post anything to the `default` room. Clients connecting to the server are interested only in specific rooms and not all rooms.

How can clients connect to a specific room that they are interested in? The client connect URL has information about the server and namespace but nothing about a room.  So, how should the client tell the server which room it wants to connect to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all send the room name with event from client side

## client side

```
io.emit('room', {room_name : 'test'});
```

## on server side

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('room', function(data){

            socket.join(data.room_name);
    }); 
});
```